# Collections in Adobe Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, collections, frameworks

Is there any open source collection framework, written in ActionScript that would emulate HashMap, HashSet, LinkedHashMap and LinkedHashSet Java class implementations.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

AS3Commons Collections include (besides others):

- ArrayList, SortedList
- Set, LinkedSet, SortedSet
- Map, LinkedMap, SortedMap
- LinkedList, Treap

The project is currently the first address for a serious AS collections framework: It consists of a high level framework architecture, the most comprehensive set of different collections and the fastest collection implementations. Additionally, most of the collections come in a bindable version to be connected to user interfaces.

[AS3Commons Collections | .../as3commons-collections/](http://sibirjak.com/osflash/projects/as3commons-collections/)

[Collections Performance Tests | .../collections-framework-performance-comparision/](http://sibirjak.com/osflash/blog/collections-framework-performance-comparision/)

[AS3Commons Organization | http://as3commons.org/](http://as3commons.org/)

And, yes, I am the author :-)

Answer (score 3):

[Eric Feminella's HashMap](http://www.ericfeminella.com/blog/2006/12/05/as3-hashmap-for-flex/) is very nice.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Lite Collections](http://sibirjak.com/blog/index.php/lite-collections/) for ActionScript 3. We are currently talking with the author about making this an [AS3Commons](http://www.as3commons.org) project.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [AS3 Data Structures](https://github.com/polygonal/ds/tree/master/src/de/polygonal/ds) (AS3Ds) by [polygonal](http://lab.polygonal.de/)

Comment: -1 no updates, no wiki, no issues and only 6 files in library