# Is Object the preferred Associative Container in AS3?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, data-structures

I've been using Object as a way to have a generic associative array (map/dictionary) since AS3/Flex seems to be very limited in this regard. But I really don't like it coming from a C++/Java/C# background. Is there a better way, some standard class I've not come across... is this even considered good/bad in AS3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Actionscript uses `Object` as a generic associative container and is considered the standard way of doing this.

There is also a `Dictionary` class available, `flash.utils.Dictionary`.

The difference is that `Dictionary` can use any value as a key, including objects, while `Object` uses string keys.  For most uses, `Object` is preferred as it is faster and covers the majority of use cases.

You can see the details on `Object` here: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Object.html
and `Dictionary` here: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/Dictionary.html
and the differences between them here: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=10_Lists_of_data_4.html

Comment: Is flash.utils available to Flex applications?

Comment: Yes it is, I just tested it in Flex Builder 3 and it is available.  I also added another link that describes the differences between them in more detail.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid there's no *native* alternative to `Object` or `Dictionary` for maps and other structures. As for *standard*, well, it depends on how one defines standard, but there are a couple of known libraries that you might like to check out if you look for Java style collections.

Like this one:

http://sibirjak.com/blog/collections/as3commons-collections/

Also, you could take a look at this question, that has links to a couple of ds libraries (including the above one).

[Collections in Adobe Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979489/collections-in-adobe-flex)

I wouldn't say using Objects is either good or bad practice. In the *general case* they are faster than any Actionscript alternative (since they are native), but less featured. Sometimes the provided functionality is good enough. Sometimes, it's a bit bare-bones, so something more structured could help you getting rid of lower level details in your code and focusing in your "domain logic", so to speak.

In the end, all of these libraries implement their data structures through Objects, Dictionaries and Arrays (or Vectors). So, if the native objects are fine for your needs, I'd say go with them. On the other hand, if you find yourself basically re-writting, say, an ad-hoc Set, perhaps, using one of these libs would be a wise choice.

Comment: Thanks. I would not really want to use some 'random' library unless it is a de facto standard, like Apache Commons in Java... I might as well work on my own.

Comment: Hey John, we are very poor in AS with standard libraries. In your case, the AS3Commons collections are the best what you can get in the web.